# ACL "fuzzy" comparision

Tags: arrays, powershell, comparison, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to compare ACLs on a folder with a reference set of ACLs, and then list any exceptions. The "fuzzy" part of the equation is that I want to be able to disregard any unknown SID. So creating a reference folder with the perms I want to test won't work to use Compare-Object between it and my test folder.

The underlying scenario is that I am cleaning up old user directories where the actual user account has been deleted (this is where the non-resolved SID comes in). By default, the folders include perms for Administrator and the like, which I don't care about. There are some folders, however, where another user has been granted explicit permissions, and I want to capture these. Unfortunately, there aren't any shortcuts I can use to check: e.g. -IsInherited or the like to exclude ACLs I don't care about.

Per the below, I can dump the ACLs out into an array

```
$acl = get-acl f:\user_folder
$access = $acl.Access | ForEach-Object { $_.identityReference.value }

$access
BUILTIN\Administrators
MYDOMAIN\JBLOGGS
S-1-5-21-4444444444-9999999-1111111111-74390
MYDOMAIN\Domain_Group   ###Yes, the group has an underscore in the name
```

I can create another array of the users I want to ignore, including a partial string to match any unresolved SID.

```
 $defaults = @("BUILTIN\Administrators","MYDOMAIN\DomainGroup","S-1-5-21")
```

So how do I compare my `$defaults` array with the `$access` array and output only the exceptions like "MYDOMAIN\JBLOGGS"?

I'm trying a foreach, but I'm stumped about grabbing that exception. The following still outputs the SID I want to avoid. I'm hoping to also avoid too many nested "IFs".

```
$access | ForEach { If ($defaults -notcontains $_) { Write-Output $_ } }
MYDOMAIN\JBLOGGS
S-1-5-21-4444444444-9999999-1111111111-74390  #Do not want!
```

If I put the wildcard `$_*` into the `-notcontains`, I get the whole contents of `$access` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it was fairly simple, thanks to the help above.

I managed to omit the fact in the original question where I required it to work in Powershell v2.

```
$defaults = @("BUILTIN\Administrators","MYDOMAIN\DomainGroup")
$acl = get-acl $folder
    $access = $acl.Access | ForEach-Object { $_.identityReference.value }
    # check that no other account still has access to the folder
    $access | ForEach { 
        If ($defaultACL -notcontains $_ -and $_ -notlike 'S-1-5-21*') { 
            write-output "Extra perms:$user $_"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this:

```bsh
$defaults = 'BUILTIN\Administrators', 'MYDOMAIN\DomainGroup', 'S-1-5-21*'

$acl.Access | Where-Object {
    $id = $_.IdentityReference
    -not ($defaults | Where-Object { $_ -like $id })
} | Select-Object -Expand value
```

`$defaults | Where-Object { $_ -like $id }` does a wildcard match of the given identity against all items of `$defaults`. The wildcard `*` at the end of `S-1-5-21*` allows to match all strings starting with `S-1-5-21`. The negation `-not` inverts the result so that only identities not having a match in `$defaults` pass the filter.

Comment: Thanks for unaccepting my answer three years later.

Comment: I actually meant to upvote it rather than accept it as an answer originally, since the code didn't work, but it was a useful pointer. I came across this again by accident and decided to fix it up. Sorry for forgetting the upvote, but you can add it to your 147k rep now.

Comment: The code probably didn't work for you originally b/c I had used `$access` instead of `$acl.Access`, which in your code is the already expanded identity references. Presumably I had set `$access = $acl.Access` when doing test-runs, and then just copy/pasted it. That part is fixed now. And to be very clear, I'm not concerned about a couple points rep.

Answer (score 0):

give the users you want to ignore some right on a dummy folder, get the acl of that folder and then compare whith the acl of your actual folder

```
$genericACL = get-acl c:\temp\dummy
$folderacl = get-acl f:\user_folder
$exceptions= $folderacl.Access.identityreference.value |?{ ($_ -notin $genericACL.access.identityreference.value) -and ($_.strartswith('S-1-5-21') -eq $false))  }
```

Comment: There's no "-notin" in Powershell. I tried to rework this with "-notcontains", but I think I'd have to run it through a foreach loop.

Comment: @Trix `notin` and `in` operators was introduced in powershell V3

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to state it needs to Powershell 2.0

Comment: @Trix no, it's me who have not paid attention to your tags ;)